# can't see my site after log in

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

i've got a error in my 'index.php' for my membre area for my site i've got those error

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host
>   'srv9.000webhost.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
>   in /home/a8479867/public_html/pages/index.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid
>   MySQL-Link resource in /home/a8479867/public_html/pages/index.php on
>   line 7
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'a8479867'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/a8479867/public_html/pages/index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in /home/a8479867/public_html/pages/index.php
>   on line 11

Error SQL !

```
SELECT count(*) FROM membre WHERE login="momo1o4" AND pass_md5="b83287a789719ce4a412b0b9da582cee"
Access denied for user 'a8479867'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Here is my Code

```
<?php
// on teste si le visiteur a soumis le formulaire de connexion
if (isset($_POST['connexion']) && $_POST['connexion'] == 'Connexion') {
    if ((isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['login'])) && (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))) {

    $base = mysql_connect ('server', 'login', 'password');
    mysql_select_db ('nom_base', $base);

    // it tests whether a database entry contains the couple login / pass
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM membre WHERE login="'.mysql_escape_string($_POST['login']).'" AND pass_md5="'.mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass'])).'"';
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($req);

    mysql_free_result($req);
    mysql_close();

    // if a response is obtained, then the user is a member
    if ($data[0] == 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
        header('Location: membre.php');
        exit();
    }
    // if there is no response, the visitor was wrong either in his login or password in
    elseif ($data[0] == 0) {
        $erreur = 'Compte non reconnu.';
    }
    // if not, then there is a big problem :)
    else {
        $erreur = 'Probème dans la base de données : plusieurs membres ont les mêmes identifiants de connexion.';
    }
    }
    else {
    $erreur = 'Au moins un des champs est vide.';
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Accueil</title>
</head>

<body>
Connexion à l'espace membre :<br />
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Login : <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['login'])) echo htmlentities(trim($_POST['login'])); ?>"><br />
Mot de passe : <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass'])) echo htmlentities(trim($_POST['pass'])); ?>"><br />
<input type="submit" name="connexion" value="Connexion">
</form>
<a href="inscription.php">Vous inscrire</a>
<?php
if (isset($erreur)) echo '<br /><br />',$erreur;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think error is descriptive ... `Access denied for user 'a8479867'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` ... make sure your username and password for database connection is correct

Comment: Obviously, there is an issue in username for your MySQL server. Make sure you're using correct username, password and hostname.

Comment: Problem is with your database connection. You haven't provide any password to database connection.

Comment: can you tell me how to add a password to my database please ?

Comment: here my database

CREATE TABLE membre (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 login text NOT NULL,
 pass_md5 text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;

Comment: Sidenote: md5 should **not** be used for hashing passwords, also you really should port your sql code to mysqli or PDO. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: is `srv9.000webhost.com` your db server  or your web server?

Comment: i'm not really sure i'm only a novice in php so i don't know i've create a database on 000webhost.com the serve link is srv9.000webhost.com

my web server is http://harrypotterthegoodandthebad.site88.net/

i think.. ahah not really sure pretty lost this is my first big project :-P

Comment: help ? please :-) i don't really understand what i'm suppost to do

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to connect to mysql using your ftp username (a8479867) but I'm pretty sure you still need to manually add that user (with a proper password) to mysql.

There should be an option in your webhost panel to create mysql users and update their passwords.